# Linking problem in assembly code

Tags: ubuntu, glibc, assembly

Here is my assembly code:

```asm
.section .data
    mystring: .asciz    "Hello world\n"

.section .text
.globl  _start
_start:

pushl   $0
pushl   $mystring
call    printf

pushl   $0
call    exit
```

I am trying to assemble and link this code in my 64 bit ubuntu machine **in 32 bit mode**. This code is assembled successfully with this command :

```shell
as -32 demo.s -o demo.o
```

but when i try to link it with ld command :

```shell
ld -m elf_i386 -s demo.o -o demo -lc
```

its giving this error :

```
ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so when searching for -lc
ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a when searching for -lc
ld: cannot find -lc: No such file or directory
ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so when searching for -lc
```

What should I do for this?

This is my `libc.so` locations:

```
libcjson.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcjson.so.1
    libc.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    libc.so.6 (libc6) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

Comment: How about explicitly specify path to lib? - `ld -m elf_i386 --dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -lc -s demo.o -o demo`

Comment: You may change `as`  to `gcc` with changing the entry point `_start` to `main`

Comment: i solved this problem by installing this library libc6-dev-i386 but before installing we have to run these two commands sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 and sudo apt update.